# Creating a macro that uses a function with a variable

Tags: function, excel, sum, vba

Heres my code:

```
Dim N As Single
N = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).Value
E = 1 - N

ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=-SUM(R[E]C:R[-1]C)"
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=-SUM(R[E]C:R[-1]C)"
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=-SUM(R[E]C:R[-1]C)"
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
```

I want the macro user to select a cell with a value (example 5) as it will be a slot for the 5th row of values. I want the program to find the negative sum of all the values prior to it (1,2,3 and 4).

Comment: I think I can answer this question with a much better solution then you seem to be trying for, but can you please be more clear on the data you have and what you want to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

Though I am not in favor of `.Select`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select/10718179#10718179).

But is this what you are trying? `E` is a variable. Inside the double quotes it behaves as a string :)

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim N As Single
    N = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).Value
    E = 1 - N

    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=-SUM(R[" & E & "]C:R[-1]C)"
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=-SUM(R[" & E & "]C:R[-1]C)"
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=-SUM(R[" & E & "]C:R[-1]C)"
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: It is possible that this is what the OP asked for - but is this just encouraging ugly code?

Comment: No I am not encouraging ugly code ;) Please see the first line of my post. My post focuses primarily on how to use a variable with a string :)

Comment: Fair enough about the first line!

Answer (score 0):

Might I suggest the below as an alternative avoiding the use of SELECT?

```
Sub SampleWithoutSelect()
Dim N As Single
N = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).Value
E = 1 - N

for iIndx=0 to -3 step -1
    range(activecell.offset(iindx,0).formular1c1="=-SUM(R[" & E & "]C:R[-1]C)"
next

End Sub
```

is that what you want - or am I missing something?